# While loop and generic lists

Tags: java, selenium, iterator

I have a question, I need a while generic loop to iterate through table with selenium web driver, but question is how to make double if statement inside because i need a loop to stop after it finds some text "compare string", if I insert compare into if it doesnt work.

```
List<Web element> list = locator for table elements
Iterator<Web element> iter= iter.next()
while(iterator.hasnext()&&el1.text != compare_string)
"SOME ACTION"
```

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

In Java Strings should be compared by `equals()`, not logical operators.

```
while(iterator.hasNext) && !el1.text.equals(compare_string)) {
    // ...
    if (another_stop_condition)
        break;
}
```